# argparse: parse specific options first, while having all options shown in usage hint

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments, argparse, partial

I have an application whose options handling partially depends on the value given for other options, as in

```
python tool.py --limit=s:100 stuff property
```

A simple argument parser could look like this:

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--limit')
parser.add_argument('stuff')
parser.add_argument('property')
args = parser.parse_args(['--limit', 's:100', 'something', '123'])
```

However, how the `--limit` argument must be handled depends on both `stuff` and `property`. I could make `--limit` unknown to the parser, parse only known arguments with

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args(['--limit', 's:100', 'something', '123'])
```

and pass `unknown` to a second parser which can act according to the values of `stuff` and `property`, but then I couldn't include the second parser's help in the output of `python tool.py --help`, or could I?

Answer (score 0):

You could give the first parser a custom `usage` parameter that includes all the arguments.  You could write that by hand, or fetch it from a (unused) parser that includes all arguments.

```
 astr = parser.format_usage()
```

fetches the usage string

```
 parser = ArgumentParser(usage=astr,...)
```

passes it to a new parser.  You may need to edit `astr` a bit.

Including the extra `help` lines will be trickier.  You could add them to the `description` or `epilog`.

---

The order in which arguments are parsed is determined by their order in the `sys.argv`.  The parser looks for positional arguments, then an optional, more positionals, next optional, etc until the strings are consumed.

As matter of philosophy I prefer to think of `argparse` as a parser, not a 'handler'.  It's primary purpose is to figure out what the user wants, and it give useful feedback if they want something unexpected.

Interactions between arguments are best handled after parsing.  It is possible to implement interactions with custom Action classes, but that code typically gets more complex.

In your example `--limit` occurs first, putting 's:100' in the namespace

Initial namespace with defaults:

```
namespace(limit=None, stuff=None, property=None)
```

namespace after parsing `--limit`:

```
namespace(limit='s:100', stuff=None, property=None)
```

namespace after parsing the 2 positionals:

```
namespace(limit='s:100', stuff='something', property=123)
```

The `limit` custom Action could look at the values for `stuff` and `property`, but that doesn't help if those strings come after.  Similarly, `stuff` action could look at and modify the `limit` attribute, but a latter `--limit` could overwrite that.

If you expand on how these arguments interact we could give you more concrete ideas.

---

Another thought - use one parser to handle the help, and handle `--limit` in a most general way.  Then creat or modify a new parser using the useful values from the first, and parse the input again.  The same `sys.argv` can be parsed multiple times by multiple parsers.  Nothing is destroyed in parsing.